# Yield all events in a list inside an enumerable expression

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Consider the following code:

```
IEnumerable<string> FooBar()
{
    yield return "foo";
    yield return "bar";
}

IEnumerable<string> FooBarBaz()
{
    foreach(var s in FooBar()) { yield return s; }
    yield return "baz";
}
```

Is there any way I can refactor `FooBarBaz` to directly yield everything from `FooBar()`, without having to explicitly type out the `foreach` loop?

I'd like to do something like the following, but this is of course not valid C#:

```
IEnumerable<string> FooBarBaz()
{
    yield return all FooBar();
    yield return "baz";
}
```